# Как получить доступ к пользовательскому интерфейсу с Better Discord?

Tags: java

Я новичок, и хочу написать дополнение на Better Discord. Оно должно добавить кнопку (в область красного круга), которая будет содержать кнопки, при нажатии на которых, будут отправляться некоторые сообщения. Помогите пожалуйста, даже не знаю с чего начать. Заранее спасибо!![image: ! введите сюда описание изображения]